# How to have a page break for a specified number of rows in a grid

Tags: birt

I'm designing a BIRT report that should print on a form.
On this form there is a grid with a maximum of 4 lines of informations.
Think of it as an invoice form, whit a very restrictive place for listing products ordered.

My data set may return more than 4 rows. 
In this case, I should print the remaining rows on another page.

My existing report was not designed to handle this case, which occurs not very often.

Now that I should deal with it, I have several questions :

1. Is it possible that a grid inserts a page break every x rows in the data set ?
2. There is a grand total to be displayed on the last page. What's the best way to deal with this situation ? With a footer ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can define the page break on your own by which is in masterpage layout property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a footer would be the default, and in most cases best, way to display a total.

You can specify page breaks on the Master Page. You could set it to break after a fixed length, or select the top four rows of the grid and set it break after that.

Comment: The original report design was not using the master page at all. After some cut/paste operation from the layout to the master page, it works. Thanks for that.